# Stop Outlook searching for non existing .pst file

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

Some time ago i must used .pst file in my outlook - I don't recall exactly why I needed it. I am sure, that it was not for my main outlook folder, where all my emails and addresses are.
Problem today is, that whenever I restart outlook, it always tries to search for that - today not existing - .pst file. When I start outlook dialog is opened with 'The file yyy.pst can not be found' then it shows me dialog for file searching, where I press 'Cancel' and outlook starts normally, everything is fine. How can I set outlook so it will stop showing me that dialog on start up ?  I don't need that .pst file anymore (I don't even recall why I needed it), so dialog at the start is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a programming question.

That being said, remove the bad PST store from File | Account Settings | Data files.

Comment: You really helped me a lot. That was a problem for a long time. Thank you.